# Unexpected behaviour when evaluating extension of sealed trait

Tags: scala, scope

I have a trait that looks like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  val description: String
}
```

In a different object I have the following which calls that trait:

```
object MyObject {
  sealed trait c extends MyTrait {
    val myItem: String
    val description: String = s"$myItem"
  }

  object c1 extends c {
    val myItem: String = "One"
  }

  object c2 extends c {
    val myItem: String = "Two"
  }
}
```

However, at run time, I `c1.description` and `c2.description` are both null objects. If I refactor the code to look like this, I get the expected result:

```
object MyObject {
  sealed trait c extends MyTrait {
    val myItem: String      
  }

  object c1 extends c {
    val myItem: String = "One"
    val description = s"$myItem"
  }

  object c2 extends c {
    val myItem: String = "Two"
    val description = s"$myItem"
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, all val are evaluated in order of appearance, but override val are transformed by the compiler and in the evaluated compiled code, are "under" the non override one.

So :

```
object MyObject {
  sealed trait c extends MyTrait {
    val myItem: String = "This will print this string"
    val description: String = s"$myItem"
  }

  object c1 extends c {
  }

  object c2 extends c {
  }
}
```

works,

```
object MyObject {
  sealed trait c extends MyTrait {
    val description: String = s"$myItem"
    val myItem: String = "This will not print this string"
  }

  object c1 extends c {
  }

  object c2 extends c {
  }
}
```

doesn't, and as you noticed, your way doesn't either.

The easiest thing to do is write description as a lazy val.

As a more general rule, I usually see in traits either final val (to forbid overriding), or def, to allow any kind of overriding. In your case, maybe description should be a final lazy val, and myItem a def ?

Comment: Note that changing `c#myItem` to `def` won't change anything. You need to change the implementations in `c1` and `c2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `val`s are initialized as part of the constructor. Before that, the field still exists, but has the default value (`null`/`0`/`false`/etc. depending on the type).
2. The constructor of supertype `c` is naturally executed before the constructor of subtype (`c1` or `c2`).